# Can I use default workflows for this?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-workflow

I have to create a workflow in Sharepoint online shown in the image. Below is the explanation of the workflow

[image: Project Workflow process]

A Sharepoint list form will be defined with required fields.

Step 1:
Whenever a new project requestor wants to request for resources, they use the link to create a new line item and submit
Step 2:
This item should be assigned to Manager. He will verify the details and assign it to some Lead. 
Step 3 :
Lead will work with the requestor offline to gather details about the request and comes up with level of efforts, no. of resources required, etc. and creates a form(some excel template). This form needs to be uploaded to this request and on submit, 
Step 4:
Now this item should go back to the manager. Manager will finally review the form created by the lead (and allocate resources - not part of this workflow) and closes the request, and the requests lifecycle is ended.

Is there a way I can achieve this using the inbuild workflow types given in SP online, or Should I create the workflow from scratch - I'm very new to SP, so sorry for the basic question

[image]

Comment: If you're using SharePoint Online, you should think about Power Automate (Flow) instead of the legacy workflows. There is an out of the box approval built into Lists and Libraries already. Just specify the person who needs to approve.

Comment: Using Flows will be a good option, instead of using OOTB approvals you can design your own, where you can provided the link of tlist form to specific approver(s) (in email notifications)  where they can review form and upload attachments as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the default workflow would meet your requirements. Here are two options for you:

1. Use microsoft flow to build your workflow.
2. If you do not have flow license, I would suggest you use SharePoint Designer to build your wokflow.

If you have questions to build your workflow, feel free to ask.